# Vim: behaviour change of search function in visual mode

Tags: vim

It used to be part of my Vim vocabulary... change to visual mode, place cursor to a search word, type * and all text between first and next search word would be highlighted. The highlighting can continue as long as you repeat pressing * and there is the next matching search word. Perfect set of commands to copy text, or simply as visual aid.
Coming back to Vim now after some time, this is not working on my configuration. What happens now is that only the letter under the cursor and all other such letters get highlighted.
I wonder if I have some conflict in my mappings or else? I use Vim v7.3. Anyone can help?

Comment: Sorry, messed it up initially. Each occurance of * was CTRL+* before the edit.

Comment: You might check to see if its been remapped. A newer vim would also help

Answer (score 2):

Vim does not have a visual mode command for `*`; this only works in normal mode. However, many people have a customization that supplies the *super star* visual variant, from [Search for visually selected text](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_for_visually_selected_text) - or a plugin like my [SearchHighlighting plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4320); its plugin page has links to many alternative plugins.

I guess you had something like that, too, but forgot about it. I also doubt that is was triggered by Ctrl + *; combinations of Ctrl and non-alphabetical letters mostly aren't available as unique mappings. The usual mapping is just `*`, overloading the original normal mode command for visual mode.

Vim 7.3 is from 2010 and *very* outdated. To become reacquainted with Vim (which I commend!), please choose a modern variant. It should be possible to install the latest version 8.1; if you can't find a proper package for your distribution (for Windows, check the binaries from either [vim-win32-installer](https://github.com/vim/vim-win32-installer) or [tuxproject](https://tuxproject.de/projects/vim/); on Linux, it's also not very difficult to [compile](https://www.vim.org/download.php) it yourself (e.g. from the GitHub sources).

Comment: Er, actually: * is a visual command. It just jumps to the next occurrence, as in normal mode. This seems to be what OP describes.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: That's what I mean; the behavior of `*` is the same in visual mode, there's no special behavior attached (nor documented). Whereas most people expect it to search for the selected text, not extend the selection to the next match of the current word.